# java library for reading RSS and ATOM feeds

Tags: java, rss, seam, atom-feed

I am looking for libraries which can read RSS / ATOM feeds in my J2EE application (based on JBoss Seam).

Is [Rome](http://rometools.org/) the only application there for reading feeds?

I am assuming the Seam RSS [integration](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/en-US/html/rss.html) is only for generating RSS feeds and not for reading feeds.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have you had a look into the following list? 
http://java-source.net/open-source/rss-rdf-tools

Even though it has been mentioned several times, I would suggest using [Rome](http://rometools.github.io/rome/) as well.

Comment: The Rome link points to an ads-only site.

Comment: https://github.com/rometools/rome appears to be the new location (see also https://rometools.jira.com)

Answer (score 8):

Rome is a very mature, extremely well java-documented library and is still the de facto standard for this job.

Comment: It is but it is not straightforward to read media / images..

Answer (score 3):

For Atom it is Apache Abdera: http://abdera.apache.org/

Comment: I read somewhere that it is not possible to read RSS feeds via Abdera, since most of the feeds are only in RSS I would prefer a reader which is capable of reading both RSS / Atom feeds.

I am looking for suggestions on what would someone do today, if they have to read ATOM / RSS feeds. I wouldn't prefer to use two different libraries for this purpose.

Comment: This project has been retired and should no longer be an option.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Eddie, and feed4j are other useful tools.

Answer (score 0):

For RSS feed ROME only not an option. We have lot like that namely Feed4j, abdera etc. But in these ROME only most widely used.

Answer (score 0):

Confere these links.

1. [AtomSphere](http://www.colorfulsoftware.com/projects/atomsphere)
2. [Rsspect](http://www.colorfulsoftware.com/projects/rsspect)

These are both thread safe and very fast.