# RSS Feed parser library in Java

Tags: java, parsing, rss, feed

Is there any Java helper utils/libraries available for parsing Rss/Atom feed?

I checked [RSSUtils](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/rss_utilities/) but it looks like outdated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java RSS library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113063/java-rss-library)

Comment: arg, it was the other one @Piotr mentioned, this question is about generation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at:

- [How to write an RSS feed with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113063/java-rss-library)
- [java library for reading RSS and ATOM feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729027/java-library-for-reading-rss-and-atom-feeds)

Answer (score 2):

Rome api should so the trick see http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2007/jw-11-rome.html