# How to get the number of pages/posts from a Wordpress RSS feed with a Java servlet

Tags: java, wordpress

I am coding a servlet, where I want to read in Wordpress feed. How do i get number of posts/pages from the wordpress feed? Is there any URL parameter?

And assuming that each page has fixed # of posts (6 in my case)

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress feeds use RSS, so you need to use a Java RSS library.

Question (and answer) here: [java library for reading RSS and ATOM feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729027/java-library-for-reading-rss-and-atom-feeds)

Answer, quoted:

> Have you had a look into the following list? http://java-source.net/open-source/rss-rdf-tools
>
> Even though it has been mentioned several times, I would suggest using [Rome](http://java.net/projects/rome/) as well.

**Update:** Wordpress also has an XmlRpc API, so you can use that to query posts.  The closest to I can see to getting the number of posts/pages is to use [wp.getPageList](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp#wp.getPageList) which returns an array of all posts with minimal data.

As part of the XmlRpc API support, Wordpress implements several standards including the Blogger API, for which there is a [decent tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#GettingStarted).  Again, no specific 'getPostCount()' function.

```
public static void printAllPosts(
    GoogleService myService, String blogId)
    throws ServiceException, IOException {
  // Request the feed
  URL feedUrl = new URL("http://www.blogger.com/feeds/" + blogID + "/posts/default");
  Feed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl, Feed.class);

  // Print the results
  System.out.println(resultFeed.getTitle().getPlainText());
  for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {
    Entry entry = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);
    System.out.println("\t" + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```